# How to show these two rows as one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle 11g, I have a query that returns two rows or less, somthing like this

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╗
║  Number   ║    NAME     ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1         ║    Steve    ║
║ 2         ║    John     ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

And it could also look return this

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╗
║  Number   ║    NAME     ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1         ║    Steve    ║
║ 1         ║    Steve    ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

Or this

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╗
║  Number   ║    NAME     ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1         ║    Steve    ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

I would like to rearrange the data as this

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║  whatever ║    NAME1    ║     NAME2   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║     ss    ║    Steve    ║    John     ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Or this in the other case

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║  whatever ║    NAME1    ║     NAME2   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║     ss    ║    Steve    ║    Steve    ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Or this on case of one row

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║  whatever ║    NAME1    ║     NAME2   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║     ss    ║    Steve    ║   (null)    ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

In case no rows, it should be like this

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║  whatever ║    NAME1    ║     NAME2   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║     ss    ║    (null)   ║    (null)   ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I don't want to confuse people with my failed queries, and thought of fresh start. I tried multiple sub queries that return val based on row=1 or 2, but failed as I need to pass in the number, and it seems multiple subqueries will not accept a number from outside deeper than 2 levels. also tried to use the pivot, but couldn't get my head around it, and also I don't have aggregate function here so not sure how can I use it here.

Comment: Your input data always has exactly one column and two rows? If not, what is the requirement in general? For example, what if there are three rows? Or 1 million rows?

Comment: Yes, my input data always has two columns and two rows or less.

Comment: I see a lot of description about what you want but nothing about what you've actually tried.

Comment: please read above, I updated my question

Comment: I am being banned from asking question due to this question having -4 despite it has an accepted answer, can you please vote up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_query ( id, name ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'Steve' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Steve' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT 'ss' AS whatever,
       name1,
       name2
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id, name ) AS rn
  FROM   your_query
)
PIVOT ( MAX(name) FOR rn IN (1 AS Name1, 2 AS Name2 ) );
```

**Output**:

```
WHATEVER NAME1 NAME2
-------- ----- -----
ss       Steve Steve
```

Comment: Your query works as expected and returns the values as two columns, but unfortunately I can't pass a parameter to my query inside it from out side, as I am using all your query as sub query. Good job though

Answer (score 0):

For your case where the input always contains two rows:

```
create table #mytable (number int, name varchar(50))
insert into #mytable values (1, 'Steve')
insert into #mytable values (2, 'John')

select
   M1.number as 'whatever',
   M1.name as 'Name1',
   M2.name as 'Name2'
from #mytable M1   
inner join #mytable M2
on M1.number < M2.number
```